# Weird log in problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, server, login, tty

I've been trying to figure this one out all day, and I'm no closer, so I've come to seek ideas.

I have a server instance of 20.04 LTS running on a dell blade, it's ran for years with no problems, there's no graphical stuff on it, it's pure command line. 8 cores, 24gb of ram has a dedicated BMC so I can remote into it at bios level.

I recently did and apt update/upgrade as I do quite often, and I had to restart the unit for something, and now when I restart, it just sits there at the login prompt and doesn't allow me to log-in.

This is the weird part though, it actually physically does not allow me to log in.

I try typing my user name and nothing appears on the screen, it just sits there blinking the cursor, no letters appear. I tried typing my user then return, password then return and nothing.

occasionally, the prompt disappears and I see "Stopping Getty on TTY1", "Starting Getty on TTY1" then they disappear and the login prompt returns.

Also the "ctrl + alt + number" combination to switch to different terminals is not working either, that is I cannot switch to TTY2/3/4/5/6

I can login via SSH thankfully, but monitoring the logs while trying to log in is not a great deal of help, as I see no errors or anything using "tail -f /var/log/syslog"

Completely out of ideas on where to look next, and would appreciate any suggestions folks have as this is my main GIS server with about 2TB of geospatial data and maps on it.

---

UPDATE:

Tried running agetty manually from an SSH shell

[image]

Same thing happened, a new login prompt appeared on the console, wouldn't let me enter anything, then about 30 seconds later the copy I ran at SSH just stopped running, returned me back to SSH command line, and no errors or output or anything....

Main tty cleared and reset itself....

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: why do I need to read them?  my question is perfectly clear and understandable.  I've been asking and answering questions for years on various stack sites now, and that's the first time I've been told I don't know how to ask one!